# Slim PHP : Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain, slim

I am working on a php application using slim micro framework

That is my index.php file:

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
include 'db.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get("/", function () {
    echo "<h1>HELLO USER</h1>";
});

    //Registration view

    $app->post("/reg", function (){

        $request = $this->app->request();
        $username = $request->post('username');
        $password = $request->post('password');        
        $name = $request->post('name');
        $email = $request->post('email');
        try { 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash, name, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :name, :email)";
            $s = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindParam("username", $username);
            $s->bindParam("hash", $password);            
            $s->bindParam("name", $name);
            $s->bindParam("email", $email);
            $s->execute();
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }); // Login Function End



$app->get('/updates', function () {
    //Display users

});


// run the Slim app

$app->run();

?>
```

and i have index.html file with ajax cross domain request like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>INDEX</title>
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#put").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/slim/reg',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: $("#put").serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {console.log(data); }
        }); 
    });
});



</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="put">
    Registration <br/>
    username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
    password: <input type="password" name="hash" /><br />
    name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that when i try and submit the form in my index.html file i always get:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\slim\index.php on line 19

Comment: Did you try remove the `$this->?`

Comment: I made line 19 like this : $request = $app->request();

I have got an error in the console :
500 Internal server error

Answer (score 1):

```
$request = $this->app->request();
```

This is most likely line #19 and it's not inside an instance method, not even within a class definition. So, there is no instance reference and therefore no $this.
What do you expect $this to be? Apparently you need an `app` and an `dbh`. What is providing those properties/instances?
`app` could be `$app = new \Slim\Slim();`. But what is `dbh` supposed to be? (a database handle, ok, but what is providing this database connection handle?)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is what @VolkerK mentioned.

If you want your closure method to know about variables defined outside the scope of your method you'll want to use the `use` keyword.

```
$app->post("/reg", function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app->request();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
The full working index.php now look like:

```
<?php


require 'Slim/Slim.php';
include 'db.php';   

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->contentType('application/json');

$app->get('/', 'home');
$app->post('/adduser', 'addUser');
$app->get('/users', 'getUsers');

// Home view

function home() {echo "Welcome to the platform !";}

// Add users
function addUser() {
  global $app;
  $req = $app->request();

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fullname, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :fullname, :email)";
  try {
    $db = getDB();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam("username", $_POST['username']);
      $password = md5($_POST['password']);
      $stmt->bindParam("password", $password);
      $stmt->bindParam("fullname", $_POST['fullname']);
      $stmt->bindParam("email", $_POST['email']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $db = null;
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Connection Error";
  }
}

// Get Users

function getUsers() {
    $sql = "SELECT username,fullname,email FROM users ORDER BY id";
    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo '{"users": ' . json_encode($users) . '}';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

// run the Slim app

$app->run();

?>
```

Comment: I would really try to stay away from using `global`.